# slickgrids with columns from dynamic json data

Tags: json, slickgrid

I have a dynamic json data having the format

var cols= { "columns" :  ["name","age", "Amount", "Date"]}

I need to set columns in slickgrid from dynamic data as in the format given above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `grid.setColumns({your new columns})` when your data loads.