# How to bind a Gridview in HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html, gridview

Hello Intelligent guys,

I am beginner in HTML5 and jQuery. I have learned few basic things of HTML5 and jQuery.
There is a situation where i need to bind a Gridview in HTML5 or I can use jQuery plugin.

For Gridview data, i want to use WCF service.

I have searched on google but didn't find any demo or tutorial.

Thanks.

Comment: Please take a moment to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry for my bad English. I will take care of this and also wont repeated this again.

Comment: It's not an issue with language, it's that your question doesn't show what you've tried prior to asking a question. You should also avoid things like "Please help" and "Thanks in advance".

Comment: I got your point. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many JQuery plugins are available to satisfy your need.

One I would personally recommend is following

[Handsontable](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Excel-like-Data-Grid-Editor-For-jQuery-handsontable/)

And also the following are some added benifit jquery plugins.

[JEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html) , [Ext JS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/grid/cell-editing.html) ,

[SlickGrid](https://github.com/Celebio/SlickGrid) - You can handle million of records without any trouble by this plugin.

I hope it satisfies your need.

Comment: Thank you Sir.
Now I am able to bind Gridview however I have one more question.
Can I also bind dynamically?
For example :- When I send five columns from WCF , so Its automatically bind with same name column name which I send from json. I dont want to fix column name in HTML page.
Hope you get my question

Comment: @user3292436

Go and work it with the above jquery plugins. All the plugins will do your work, Only thing is YOU DONT KNOW THAT. So please try to study those plugins. 

The following answers might help you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894139/slickgrids-with-columns-from-dynamic-json-data][1]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902061/slickgrids-with-dynamic-json-data][2]